# JQuery Ajax Upload File - Selectors not working in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have created an ajax upload file and i am have some simple problems, I have callbacks that allow you to check the file size, file format, progress, when the upload finished and starts. Now the problem lies when the file has finished. When the upload starts the Ajax gif image loader displays to $(xxx).show() then the obvious is when the upload finishes i want the Ajax gif image loader to hide $(xxx).hide() but in Mozilla the selectors are not working to hide the Ajax gif image loaders but works in IE, very strange. The code below is the full source in JQuery Ajax Upload using a .NET module to handle the upload requests.

### MODULE

```
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls
Imports API.HTML.Controls
Imports System.IO

Public Class JQueryFileUploadModule
Implements IHttpModule


Public Sub Dispose() Implements System.Web.IHttpModule.Dispose

End Sub

Public Sub Init(ByVal context As System.Web.HttpApplication) Implements System.Web.IHttpModule.Init

    AddHandler context.BeginRequest, AddressOf OnBeginRequest

End Sub

Public Sub OnBeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim httpApplication As HttpApplication = CType(sender, HttpApplication)
    Dim contextPage As HttpContext = CType(sender, HttpApplication).Context

    If contextPage.Request.QueryString("request") IsNot Nothing Then
        If contextPage.Request.QueryString("request") = "getfilesize" Then

            Dim fileNameQuesryString As String = contextPage.Request.QueryString("file")
            Dim count As Integer = 0

            If contextPage.Request.Files.Count > 0 AndAlso contextPage.Request.Files(0).FileName <> "" Then

                Dim httpPostedFile As HttpPostedFile = contextPage.Request.Files(0)
                Dim contentLength As String = httpPostedFile.ContentLength.ToString

                contentLength = CInt(contentLength) / 1024

                Dim javascript As String = String.Empty
                javascript += "$(document).ready(function() {" & Environment.NewLine
                javascript += String.Format("  window.parent.$.fn.fileUpload.GetFileSize('{0}');", contentLength) & Environment.NewLine
                javascript += "});" & Environment.NewLine

                contextPage.Response.Clear()
                contextPage.Response.Write(String.Format("<html><head><script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>{0}</script></head><body></body></html>", javascript, contentLength))
                contextPage.Response.End()
            End If
        ElseIf contextPage.Request.QueryString("request") = "savefile" Then

            Dim fileNameQuesryString As String = contextPage.Request.QueryString("file")
            Dim savePath As String = contextPage.Request.QueryString("savePath")

            Dim httpPostedFile As HttpPostedFile = contextPage.Request.Files(0)
            Dim contentLength As String = httpPostedFile.ContentLength.ToString

            Dim folderPath As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(savePath & "/")
            Dim directory As New DirectoryInfo(folderPath)
            If Not directory.Exists Then
                directory.Create()
            End If

            Dim remotePath As New FileInfo(folderPath & "/" & fileNameQuesryString)

            Dim os As New System.IO.FileStream(remotePath.FullName, IO.FileMode.Create)

            Dim inputStream As System.IO.Stream = HttpPostedFile.InputStream

            Dim length = HttpPostedFile.ContentLength

            Dim b(1) As Byte
            Dim bb As Byte
            While length > 0 AndAlso inputStream.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > -1

                os.Write(b, 0, b.Length)

                length -= b.Length

            End While
            os.Close()
            os.Dispose()
        ElseIf contextPage.Request.QueryString("request") = "fileprogress" Then

            Dim fileNameQuesryString As String = contextPage.Request.QueryString("file")
            Dim savePath As String = contextPage.Request.QueryString("savePath")

            Dim remotePath As New FileInfo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(savePath & "/" & fileNameQuesryString))

            Dim fileSizeDone As Integer = 0
            If remotePath.Exists Then
                fileSizeDone = remotePath.Length
            Else

            End If

            Dim javascript As String = String.Empty
            javascript += "$(document).ready(function() {" & Environment.NewLine
            javascript += String.Format("  window.parent.$.fn.fileUpload.SavingFile({0});", fileSizeDone / 1024) & Environment.NewLine
            javascript += "});" & Environment.NewLine

            contextPage.Response.Clear()
            contextPage.Response.Write(String.Format("<html><head><script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>{0}</script></head><body></body></html>", javascript))
            contextPage.Response.End()

        End If
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

### JQUERY PLUGIN AjAX UPLOAD

```
(function($) {

$.fn.fileUpload = function(settings) {

    var def = {
        fileSizeLimit: 2048,
        fileExtAllowed: '',
        iframe: null,
        fileFormatCheck: function() { },
        fileSizeError: function() { },
        fileProgress: function() { },
        finish: function() { },
        start: function() { },
        savePath: '/'
    }

    var container = this;
    var fileInputName = '';
    var fileInputExt = '';
    var fileLength = 0;
    var formAction = $("form").attr("action");

    settings = $.extend(def, settings);

    iframe = $("<iframe id='fileupload' name='fileupload'/>");
    $(iframe).css("display", "none");

    $(iframe).insertAfter(this);

    iframe2 = $("<iframe id='fileupload2' name='fileupload2'/>");
    $(iframe2).css("display", "none");

    $(iframe2).insertAfter(this);

    var SubmitFormForFielSizeRequest = function(text) {

        $("form").attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
        $("form").attr("target", 'fileupload');

        if (GetWindowURL().indexOf("?") != -1) {
            $("form").attr("action", GetWindowURL() + '&request=getfilesize&file=' + text)
        }
        else {
            $("form").attr("action", GetWindowURL() + '?request=getfilesize&file=' + text)
        }

        $("form").submit();

    };

    var SubmitFormForFileSaveProcess = function(text) {

        $("form").attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
        $("form").attr("target", 'fileupload');

        if (GetWindowURL().indexOf("?") != -1) {
            $("form").attr("action", GetWindowURL() + '&request=savefile&file=' + text + '&savepath=' + settings.savePath)
        }
        else {
            $("form").attr("action", GetWindowURL() + '?request=savefile&file=' + text + '&savepath=' + settings.savePath)
        }
        $("form").submit();

    };

    var SubmitFormForFileProgressCheck = function(text) {

        $("form").attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
        $("form").attr("target", 'fileupload2');

        if (GetWindowURL().indexOf("?") != -1) {
            $("form").attr("action", GetWindowURL() + '&request=fileprogress&file=' + text + '&savepath=' + settings.savePath)
        }
        else {
            $("form").attr("action", GetWindowURL() + '?request=fileprogress&file=' + text + '&savepath=' + settings.savePath)
        }
        $("form").submit();

    };

    var GetWindowURL = function() {

        return window.location.href;

    };

    var GetFileName = function() {

        var text = $(container).attr("value");
        var fileName = '';

        var splitText = text.split("\\");

        if (splitText.length > 1) {
            fileName = splitText[splitText.length - 1];
        }
        else {
            fileName = text;
        }

        return fileName;

    };

    var GetFileExt = function() {

        var fileExtSplit = GetFileName().split(".");
        var fileExt = fileExtSplit[fileExtSplit.length - 1];

        return fileExt;

    };

    $(this).change(function() {

        if (settings.fileExtAllowed != GetFileExt()) {
            settings.fileFormatCheck.call(this, GetFileExt());
        }
        else {

            SubmitFormForFielSizeRequest(GetFileName());
        }


    });

    $.fn.fileUpload.GetFileSize = function(size) {

        if (size > settings.fileSizeLimit) {

            $("form").attr("action", formAction);
            settings.fileSizeError.call(this, size);

        }
        else {
            fileLength = size;
            SubmitFormForFileSaveProcess(GetFileName());
            settings.start.call(this, GetFileName());
            setTimeout(function() { $.fn.fileUpload.SavingFile(0); }, 2000);
        }

    }

    $.fn.fileUpload.SavingFile = function(progress) {

        var len = parseInt(fileLength).toFixed(0);
        var prog = parseInt(progress).toFixed(0);
        if (len <= prog) {
            $("form").attr("enctype", "");
            $("form").attr("action", formAction);
            settings.finish.call(this, GetFileName());
        }
        else {
            SubmitFormForFileProgressCheck(GetFileName());
            this.SavingProgress(progress);
        }


    }

    $.fn.fileUpload.SavingProgress = function(progress) {

        settings.fileProgress.call(this, fileLength, progress);

    }

}

})(jQuery);
```

### INSTALLATION

```
$("#htmlinputfilecreateroom").fileUpload({ fileExtAllowed: 'jpg', fileSizeLimit: 2048, savePath: 'docs',

        fileFormatCheck: function(format) {

            if (format != 'jpg') {
            }

        },

        fileSizeError: function(size) {
        },

        fileProgress: function(length, progress) {

        },

        start: function(fileName) {

            $(".imageselectedcreaterromloader").show();

        },

        finish: function(fileName) {

            $(".imageselectedcreaterromloader").hide(); //Doesnt hide here but works in ie
            $(".imageselectedcreaterrom").css("backgroundImage", "url('docs/" + fileName + "')");//Image doesnt display but works in ie

        }




    });
```

Comment: i think it might be to do with when the form action is changed

Comment: i tried to change the form action attribute back to its original setting but Mozilla doesn't seem to want to change the form action attribute when the file has finished downloading.